# Migrate sharded mongo cluster from one cloud service to another

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

We are migrating mongodb (shared cluster architecture) from a cloud service to another. Let's call C1 (source) and C2 (dest).

All of mongodb and mongos instances are bind with private ip (not using domain as expected) in C1. i stoped all instances of C1, copied to C2 successfully. But the new cluster C2 cannot run on copied data, because new cluster has different network configuration (ip, domain of shard servers and configuration servers).

How can i get rid of this problem? thanks.

Comment: anybody can help?